Using a variable from another loop without getting a bool error
So I have this code for outputting schema, which works correctly, but it gives me a bool error. "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"
I am grabbing the address variables from another loop on the page $map_location and adding the sub variables into $contact_numbers. As they both share the same content.
Is there a relatively easy way around this?
    /**
     * 'wp_head' callback
     * Insert structured data into head
     */
    public function add_address_schema() {
        // Return if not hospital post.
        if ( get_post_type() !== 'location' ) {
            return;
        }

        global $luna;
        $id_post         = get_the_id();
        $map_location    = get_field( 'map_location', $id_post );
        $contact_numbers = get_field( 'contact_numbers', $id_post );
        $thumbnail_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id( $id_post );
        $location_type   = $luna->utils->get_the_primary_term( 'location-type', $id_post );

        $address_schema = [
            '@context' => 'https://schema.org',
            '@type'    => $location_type ? $location_type->name : __( 'Hospital', 'luna' ),
            'name'     => get_the_title( $id_post ),
            'url'      => get_the_permalink( $id_post ),
        ];
        
        if ( $thumbnail_id ) {
            $address_schema['image'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $id_post, 'large' );
        }
        
        if ( $map_location ) {
            $address_schema['address'] = [
                '@type'           => 'PostalAddress',
                'streetAddress'   => $map_location['address'],
                'addressLocality' => $map_location['city'],
                'addressRegion'   => $map_location['state'],
                'postalCode'      => $map_location['post_code'],
                'addressCountry'  => $map_location['country_short'],
            ];
        
            $address_schema['geo'] = [
                '@type'     => 'GeoCoordinates',
                'latitude'  => $map_location['lat'],
                'longitude' => $map_location['lng'],
            ];
        }
        
        if ( $contact_numbers && is_array( $contact_numbers ) ) {
            $address_schema['department'] = [];
            foreach ( $contact_numbers as $contact ) {
                $address_schema['department'][] = [
                    '@type'     => $location_type ? $location_type->name : __( 'Hospital', 'luna' ),
                    'name'      => $contact['label'],
                    'telephone' => $contact['number'],
                    '@type'           => 'PostalAddress',
                'streetAddress'   => $map_location['address'],
                'addressLocality' => $map_location['city'],
                'addressRegion'   => $map_location['state'],
                'postalCode'      => $map_location['post_code'],
                'addressCountry'  => $map_location['country_short'],
                ];
                
                
            }
            
        }

        echo '<!-- Auto generated address structured data --><script type="application/ld+json">' . wp_json_encode( $address_schema, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) . '</script>';
    }
}


Who line is causing the error message? You have a lot of array keys here.

It's this bit under $contact_numbers as $contact
'@type'           => 'PostalAddress',
                'streetAddress'   => $map_location['address'],
                'addressLocality' => $map_location['city'],
                'addressRegion'   => $map_location['state'],
                'postalCode'      => $map_location['post_code'],
                'addressCountry'  => $map_location['country_short'],
                ];


You probably need to put that in the same code block of if ( $map_location ). You're assuming $map_location exists for that code block instead of checking its existence.

You should also check, if it's an array, like you did with the variable $contact_numbers. You can do that with is_array($map_location).

        if ( $contact_numbers && is_array( $contact_numbers ) ) {
        $address_schema['department'] = [];
        foreach ( $contact_numbers as $contact ) {
            $address_schema['department'][] = [
                '@type'     => $location_type ? $location_type->name : __( 'Hospital', 'luna' ),
                'name'      => $contact['label'],
                'telephone' => $contact['number'],
                ];
                if ( $map_location ) {
                $address_schema['address'] = [
            
            'streetAddress'   => $map_location['address'],
            'addressLocality' => $map_location['city'],
            'addressRegion'   => $map_location['state'],
            'postalCode'      => $map_location['post_code'],
            'addressCountry'  => $map_location['country_short'],
            ];
                }
            
        }
        
    }

